# spray-json JsonFormat case classes

Tags: json, scala, spray-json

I'm facing this problem trying to implement a JsonFormat object for a case class that is Generic.
This is my class:

```
case class SimpleQuery[T](field : String, op : Operator, value : T) extends Query{
  def getType = ????
}
```

I'm trying to use the Format that the github page of spray json hints like this :

```
implicit def SimpleQueryJsonFormat[A <: JsonFormat] = jsonFormat4(SimpleQuery.apply[A])
```

But I get this compiler error

```
trait JsonFormat takes type parameters
```

The example from spray-json github page is the following:

```
case class NamedList[A](name: String, items: List[A])

object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit def namedListFormat[A :JsonFormat] = jsonFormat2(NamedList.apply[A])
}
```

That seems really similar to mine.

I'll also open an issue in the github page.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be confusing the `<:` and the `:` in the type parameter of the definition.

In yours, `[A <: JsonFormat]` means "`A` extends `JsonFormat`".

In the example, `[A :JsonFormat]` means "`A` with an implicit `JsonFormat[A]`". It is the same as requiring an implicit (but unamed) parameter, eg `implicit aFormat: JsonFormat[A]`. This is needed to format the `value: T` part of your class.

TL;DR, try switching the `<:` to a `:`